# Locating an element within another element

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests

```
public LocatedCarParksMap locateAndClickOnTheCardByAddressIndicator(String location) {
            List<WebElement> quoteCards = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".quote-card"));
    
            for (WebElement webElement : quoteCards) {
                WebElement locationElement = webElement.findElement(By.cssSelector(".quote-card-asset-location"));
                if (locationElement.getText().equals(location)) {
                    webElement.findElement(By.xpath(".rate-card-description")).click();
                }
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            return this;
        }
```

[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU6mI.jpg)

1. Locating list of cards
2. iterating through it and locating needed card by locating the element that contains the address i am looking for
3. if address is the one i am looking for i am trying to find .rate-card-description within the same card element and then clicking on it to proceed further

I have debugged it and it does locates the address from the card however it cant locate an element within the yellow text are for me to click on

What i am doing wrong, thank you

Comment: webElement.findElement(By.xpath(".rate-card-description")).click();. Did you try changing By.xpath to By.cssSelector?

Comment: @itronic1990 Your's should be the answer. You may write down it in Answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Use Explicit Wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait =newWebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath('Locator'))
```

Or use:

```
elementToBeClickable()
```